# Airflow GCSToBigQueryOperator is reordering my columns

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have the following operators in my DAG. They are receiving data from my MySQL database, uploading it to GCS, and then importing it to BigQuery. It runs great! With one small issue...

I can see that, inbetween the `create` and `import` tasks, the target table is created in BigQuery with the schema specified in the `schema` argument, with the correct column ordering. But, as soon as the `import` task runs, the schema of the table changes, and the columns are reordered into a seemingly arbitrary ordering. Why does this happen and is there a way to get BigQuery to stop doing this? I see that there are `schema_update_options` available on the operator but the documentation is quite poor...

```
            create=BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
                task_id="create",
                bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud',
                project_id="<myproject>",
                dataset_id=target_dataset,
                table_id=table_name,
                schema_fields=schema
            )
            upload=MySQLToGCSOperator(
                task_id='mysql_to_gcs', 
                mysql_conn_id='bi_mysql',
                sql=self.sql,
                bucket=self.bucket,
                filename=self.filename,
                export_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud'
            )
            import=GCSToBigQueryOperator(
                task_id='gcs_to_bigquery',
                bucket=self.bucket,
                source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                source_objects=[self.filename],
                destination_project_dataset_table="<myproject>..target_dataset.{table_name}",
                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud',
            )
            
            create >> upload >> import
```

Answer (score 0):

The re-ordering happens because you did not define the `schema_fields` inside your `GCSToBigQueryOperator` and it triggered [BigQuery Schema Auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#schema_auto-detection_for_external_data_sources) wherein

> BigQuery makes a best-effort attempt to automatically infer the schema from the source data.

In your case, to ensure the ordering of your columns is defined the way you wanted it to be, you must define `schema_fields` inside your `GCSToBigQueryOperator`.

You can already omit `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator` since `GCSToBigQueryOperator` can already **create BigQuery tables and define schemas**.

Please see updated code based on your posted question:

```py
upload=MySQLToGCSOperator(
                task_id='mysql_to_gcs', 
                mysql_conn_id='bi_mysql',
                sql=self.sql,
                bucket=self.bucket,
                filename=self.filename,
                export_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud'
            )
            create_and_import=GCSToBigQueryOperator(
                task_id='gcs_to_bigquery',
                bucket=self.bucket,
                source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                source_objects=[self.filename],
                destination_project_dataset_table="<myproject>..target_dataset.{table_name}",
                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud',
                schema_fields=schema
            )
            
            upload >> create_and_import
```

You may refer to this [GCSToBigQueryOperator Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/6.1.0/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery) for more details.